# Why are predictions from beta regression and linear regression identical?

Tags: regression, data-visualization, linear, beta-regression, effects

I'm utilizing a beta regression to predict the relationship between x and y, since y is a proportion variable confined within the interval [0,1] but has no values of either 0 or 1.

Outcomes on y only fall between [0.4,0.6] with makes the relationship between x and y appear linear when I plot predictions using the predictorEffects function.

In order to test whether a linear model provides different results, I've predicted y values for x using both a beta regression and linear regression. My code is as follows:

```
library(betareg)
library(effects)

# beta regression
model_1<-betareg(y~x1+x2+x3, data=data, link="logit")
predict(model_1, newdata=data)


# linear regression
model_2<-lm(y~x1+x2+x3, data=data, family="normal")
predict(model_2, newdata=data)
```

The predictions for y values at different values of x are identical despite using different models. My question is, how can this be? Am I doing something wrong, or are the models working correctly?

I've attached a photo of the y~x relationship plotted with predictorEffects (note that the plots are also identical whether I use betareg or lm):

[image]

Comment: Can you post the data so we can look at the models ourselves?

Comment: How do you know they are identical?

Comment: To follow up on these comments: these data are so nicely behaved that (1) beta regression is not needed and (2) *any* linear regression model should yield just about the same slope, perhaps up to several significant digits.  If you are getting *exactly* the same values, though (up to the 10-16 decimal digits expected of double precision algorithms), that would suggest you might be mistaken about what the software is doing and that would lead to different resolutions of the situation.

Comment: Thank you for your comments! I estimated the predictions using the predict function, but it turns out the predictions are only identical down to 3 decimal digits, so thanks for pointing me in the right direction. A follow up question: Does the similarity between the two models imply, that I can reasonably do sensitivity analysis using a linear model? I'm wondering this since the betareg package to my knowledge isn't compatible with either the specr or sensemakr package, which I intend to use.